# sort content in a page from database with out refreshing the page

Tags: php, html

I have a php web site. Here I have listed more contents from database table with in a div,
 My structure is

```
<table width="100%" border="0"  cellspacing="0">
  <tr bgcolor="#fbf2d8" >
    <td width="9%" height="31" class="flight_heading"><a href="#">Nmae</a></td>
    <td width="27%" class="flight_heading"><a href="#">Stop</a></td>
    <td width="11%"  class="flight_heading"><a href="#">Depart</a></td>
    <td width="10%"  class="flight_heading"><a href="#">Arrive</a></td>
    <td width="20%" class="flight_heading"><a href="#">Duration</a></td>
    <td width="13%" class="flight_heading"><a href="#">Price</a></td>
    <td width="10%" >&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr style="border:0px;">
    <td height="148" colspan="7">

    <div id="airline"><!--  starts here -->
    <table width="100%" height="136" border="0" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="5" style="font-size:12px; color:#333333;">
      <tr >
        <td width="8%" height="35"><div align="center">Name</div></td>
        <td width="29%" ><div align="left">BLR → HYD (0)</div></td>
        <td width="11%" ><div align="left">08 : 55</div></td>
        <td width="10%" ><div align="left">12 : 55</div></td>
        <td width="18%" ><div align="left">1h 25m</div></td>
        <td width="14%" ><h2 align="center">Rs. 3,805</h2></td>
        <td width="10%"><div id="book_now1"><a href="#">Book</a><a href="#" class="detail">Details</a>
        </div>        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr >
        <td height="81" colspan="7" align="center">
        <div id="airline_detail">
        <table width="100%" height="69" border="0" cellspacing="5">
  <tr>
    <td height="18" colspan="4">GOING THERE: Tuesday, 06 March, 2012</td>
    </tr>
  <tr>
    <td width="7%" height="36"><div align="center">Name</div></td>
    <td width="19%">Kingfisher Red<br /> 
      IT 2817</td>
    <td width="50%"><p><strong>Dep:</strong>    08:55   Bengaluru International, Bangalore (BLR)<br />
        <strong>Arr:</strong>   10:20   Rajiv Gandhi International, Hyderabad (HYD) </p>      </td>
    <td width="24%">    1h 25m    ECONOMY     Non Refundable</td>
  </tr>
</table>
        </div>        </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    </div><!-- ends here -->
    </td>
    </tr>
    </table>
```

I don't want to change my design. But I want to sort the fields when a user click on Name, or stop or price etc,

Is it any way to do this without refreshing the page also not change in design?

I know the sorting with in table content, but it's not applicable in the case.

I have tries to submit the page using Ajax, But after submission a need to take the sort vale (name) so that I can fetch the data from the table

Thanks in advace

Answer (score 0):

You are going to need JavaScript to do this on the front end ... if your not using jQuery then i suggest [TinyTable](http://www.scriptiny.com/2009/03/table-sorter/) ... if you are using jQuery then i suggest [DataTables](http://datatables.net/)

But i think with either one of these nested tables is going to be your biggest stumbling block !

Answer (score 0):

You can sort tables using JQuery plugins. There is a number of them, an example is [this one (SortTable)](http://www.kryogenix.org/code/browser/sorttable/)

There is also [this page, which shows 16 techniques](http://www.cssjuice.com/16-sortable-table-techniques/)